# More compact or better way to write a function that SUM multiple COUNTIFS with same criteria

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

[image: This is what my spreadsheet look like. I'm trying to make a database of certain Moba game.]

I'm trying to write a function that counts a win and lose of specific Hero, a player character, of my team (Player 1 to 5 is always the same person)

Here is what I got

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS($F$9:$F$13,$L9,$E$9:$E$13,"Win"),
COUNTIFS($G$9:$G$13,$L9,$E$9:$E$13,"Win"),
COUNTIFS($H$9:$H$13,$L9,$E$9:$E$13,"Win"),
COUNTIFS($I$9:$I$13,$L9,$E$9:$E$13,"Win"),
COUNTIFS($J$9:$J$13,$L9,$E$9:$E$13,"Win"))
```

Now I'm wondering if there is any better or more compact way to write my function?

Link to [google sheets](http://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ovyePdFo9QKBzvmHxBDDlyLhHaUUoJqijAk5mian3Uc/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you could do it by a sumproduct:

```
=sumproduct(($E$9:$E$13=M$8)*($F$9:$J$13=$L9))
```

Comment: This function is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

or you can do whole your table with one single formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"", "Win", "Lose"; QUERY(IFERROR(
 QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(F9:J<>"", "♥"&F9:J&"♦"&E9:E, )),,999^99)),,999^99), "♥")), "♦")), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2")*1, 
 QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(F9:J<>"", "♥"&F9:J&"♦"&E9:E, )),,999^99)),,999^99), "♥")), "♦")),
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2")),
 "select Col1,Col3,Col2 offset 1", 0)})
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tlrOl5xgQa-23GbB48STVbNO-U-oj2zc2fvDGSInEk8/edit#gid=0)